# How do you remove string array result until you have zero results?

Tags: c#

I have a form `Form1` with an array in it:

```
string [] lines = value2.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Where value2 is a text document like this:

```
x
y
z
```

I then have another form `Form2` that collects randomly one of the arrays to a string => `person`.
This form also has a return button that returns to `Form1`.
Person is a `public static string`.

I am trying to work out a way that when you return to `Form1` You can not use the same random value `person` again.

---

#### I have tried:

`lines = lines.Where(s => s != person).ToArray();` on the submit to `Form2` Click. But that doesn't seem to work.

---

## `Form2`:

```
namespace moving_random_to_another_page
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        string person = Form1.person;
        Form opener;

        public Form2(Form parentForm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            opener = parentForm;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            opener.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            this.label1.Text = person;
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
        }

    }
}
```

---

## `Form1`:

```
namespace moving_random_to_another_page
{
        

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static int array_lenth2;
        public static int array_lenth;
        public static string[] lines2;
        public static string[] lines;
        public static string participants;
        public static string prizes;

        public static string person;
        public static string prize;
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        static string ConvertStringArrayToString(string[] array)
        {
            //
            // Concatenate all the elements into a StringBuilder.
            //
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string value in array)
            {
                builder.Append(value);
                builder.Append("\r\n");
            }
            return builder.ToString();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
                string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                string value = File.ReadAllText(file);

                this.textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
                // Use ToCharArray to convert string to array.
                lines = value.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                array_lenth = lines.Length;
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int month = rnd.Next(0, array_lenth);
                participants = ConvertStringArrayToString(lines);
                person = lines[month];
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are these all the participants? \r\n" + participants, "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                 if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                 {
              
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     array_lenth = 0;
                     return;
                 }
                 this.textBox1.Text = file;
                 
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
                string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                string text = File.ReadAllText(file);

                string value2 = text;

                this.textBox2.ReadOnly = true;

                // Use ToCharArray to convert string to array.
                lines2 = value2.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                array_lenth2 = lines2.Length;
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int month = rnd.Next(0, array_lenth2);

                prizes = ConvertStringArrayToString(lines2);
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are these all the prizes? \r\n" + prizes, "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    array_lenth2 = 0;

                }
                this.textBox2.Text = file;
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
              
            if ( array_lenth2 == array_lenth && array_lenth > 1 && array_lenth2 > 1)
            { 
                    lines = lines.Where(s => s.ToLower() != person.ToLower()).ToArray();
                    Form2 x = new Form2(this);
                    x.Show();
                    this.Hide();
               
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error with entries. Please try again!","",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
     
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to put it into a more usable data structure like a stack or queue, then remove from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have

```
lines = lines.Where(s => s != person).ToArray();
```

*... actually works.*

Now, if it's not working, that means that your string `person` does not match any item in the `array`. Chances are either there are extra spaces, or more likely, the capitalization isn't the same.

Note that if `person` is `"X"` and lines is `{ "x", "y", "x" }` then your code won't match any item in `lines`.

Try to normalize the capitalization:

```
lines = lines.Where(s => s.ToLower() != person.ToLower()).ToArray();
```

Finally, note that if the file you're reading from has a newline at the end, you'll get an empty entry in your lines array. Then naturally if that empty string gets assigned to `person`, this code won't match that to anything in the array and won't remove any item.

To avoid this, use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` when doing your `string.Split()`:

```
lines = value.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: `person` comes directly from the array. There is no chance of it not matching.

Comment: Also I started learning c# 2 days ago. Can you explain to me what s even is?

Comment: Ok, I suggest edit your question and post that code then and we'll see further. With what you posted the above is the most detail I can think of providing

Comment: `s`? in `Where(s => s.ToLower() ... )` -- that is a `Lambda expression`; `s` is an alias given to each item of `lines` as the `Where()` expression loops through the `array`.

Comment: I have put the two forms into my question. If that helps?

Comment: I don't see the code in there where you're trying to remove anything from lines? Note also this could be due to empty entries in your string.split() call ... maybe person = lines[month] is assigning an empty value? Did you debug and check it?

Comment: I debugged your code and it works. Note that you don't do anything with lines after you remove it. Form1 label1 shows the random assignment of person. Also if your test file has a line at the end, then sometimes person will randomly be assigned an empty string. I updated my answer for this.

Comment: there are not empty strings I know that for a fact. What should I do with lines after I remove?

Comment: The empty string could be at the end of the file, when you press "enter' after the last line. I don't know what you should do with lines after you remove because I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. However the code you have actually does work :)

Comment: plus I am recording what that `person` is in `Form2` then I want it to be deleted

Comment: Put a break point on lines = lines.Where(s => s.ToLower() != person.ToLower()).ToArray();... add watch on person... and you'll see after that line executes, lines does not include whatever value person was set to.

Comment: Deleted from where, the file?

Comment: Make a new question for that; it is totally separate than what you're asking here.

Comment: I am trying to show the random string on `Form2` then return to `Form1` where I will get a new random and so on until I have no more array!

Comment: Well the problem is each time user presses button1, new file is read and your whole array gets re-made from the file. That will never happen with your code. You need to read the file once and then wire up the buttons separately. I suggest to make a new question for that but first try to do it yourself.

Comment: well I will only press button 1 once. **Not** the second time round.

Comment: That's what I am saying -- you need to wire up the code that keeps looping or button pressing or whatever to get the next random number and then remove from the array. If you press it only once, then it only removes one element from the array and only randomly assigns person. So you need to wire up another button to do the same thing the next time you click it, without opening the file again or using the OpenFileDialog at all. You have all the code already. I know you can do this!!!

Comment: The problem was the way I was showing participants and person and lines I should have wrote `Form1.person` for example